# Deploying Shiny app on Bluemix through Cloud Foundry : Fails at 15 mins

Tags: r, shiny, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I am trying to deploy an R Shiny Application on IBM Bluemix through Cloud Foundry. However, it fails after 15 minutes every time. I even attempted to change the time for the CF_STAGING_TIMEOUT and CF_STARTUP_TIMEOUT variable, but even that did not help.

I am not sure how to fix this issue. Below are the parameters that I defined in the `mainfest.yml` file:

`---
applications:

- name: MYSHINYAPP
  memory: 500M
  instances: 1
  buildpack: git://github.com/beibeiyang/cf-buildpack-r.git
  env:
    CRAN_MIRROR: https://cran.rstudio.com
    CF_STAGING_TIMEOUT: 60
    CF_STARTUP_TIMEOUT: 60`

Comment: Can you be more specific?  What fails exactly?  Can you include the error message or output you get?  Also, is your application exiting (it shouldn't, it should run forever)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The env parameters in your manifest.yml file are valid for your application container only.
To change the CF_STAGING_TIMEOUT and CF_STARTUP_TIMEOUT value you have to export them in the shell (or command line) you are running cf command line:

For example, if you are using Unix, Linux or Mac:

```
export CF_STAGING_TIMEOUT=60
cf push myapp
```

Comment: One of my colleague suggested me to use an alternative build pack .. and It worked perfect   github.com/alexkago/cf-buildpack-r